# PyTorch model not converging

Tags: pytorch

I'm training a binary classification model on a series of images.
The model was derived from `resnet18` in `torchvision` and I made the last FC as `nn.Linear(512, 1)`

The loss function is `BCELoss`

However, the model doesn't show any sign of converging even after 5000 iterations.

I'm suspecting I might do something wrong in the training stage? But I can't find where's the bug.

Here's my code:

Model:

```
## Model
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models

resnet18 = models.resnet18(pretrained= True)
resnet18.fc = nn.Linear(512, 1)
```

Parameters, loss, optimizers:

```
## parameter
epochs = 200
learning_rate = 0.1
momen = 0.9
batch = 8
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
resnet18.to(device)
opt = optim.SGD(resnet18.parameters(), lr = learning_rate, momentum = momen)
```

Dataloaders:

```
# Generators
training_set = Dataset(X_train)
training_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_set, batch_size= batch, shuffle=True)

validation_set = Dataset(X_test)
validation_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(validation_set, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
```

Training:

```
# training
history = []
for t in range(epochs):  
  for i, data in enumerate(training_generator, 0):

    inputs, labels = data
    # check if input size == batch size #
    if inputs.shape[0] < batch:
      break

#    print("labels", labels, labels.dtype)

    # move data to GPU #
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

    opt.zero_grad()
    # Prediction #
    y_pred = resnet18(inputs).view(batch,)
    y_pred = (y_pred > 0).float().requires_grad_()
#    print("y_pred", y_pred, y_pred.dtype)

    # Calculating loss #
    loss = criterion(y_pred, labels.view(batch,))
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
    
    if i % 10 == 0:
      history.append(loss.item())
      print("Epoch: {}, iter: {}, loss: {}".format(t, i, loss.item())


torch.save(resnet18, 'trained_resnet18.pt')
```

Edit:

The loss values are like this:

```
Epoch: 3, iter: 310, loss: 0.0
Epoch: 3, iter: 320, loss: 37.5
Epoch: 3, iter: 330, loss: 37.5
Epoch: 3, iter: 340, loss: 0.0
Epoch: 3, iter: 350, loss: 37.5
Epoch: 3, iter: 360, loss: 50.0
Epoch: 3, iter: 370, loss: 37.5
Epoch: 3, iter: 380, loss: 25.0
Epoch: 3, iter: 390, loss: 12.5
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by not converging, what is the loss values for a couple of iterations?

Comment: I put it in edit

Comment: See my answer and update me if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the error lies in the following line:

```
y_pred = (y_pred > 0).float().requires_grad_()
```

You try to binarize the model prediction in a weird way, I suggest do the following instead:

```
y_pred = torch.sigmoid(y_pred)
```

And pass this to the loss function.

#### Explanation

The output of the model can be any value, but we want to normalize that values to reside in the `[0,1]` range. This is exactly what the sigmoid function does. Once we have the values in the range of `[0,1]` the comparison with the binary labels will make sense, closer to 1 will be "1" and the opposite.

You can refer to the following link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsFasV46KgQ

Comment: Now I got all the same predictions as tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]

Comment: I tried commenting `y_pred = (y_pred > 0).float().requires_grad_()
` out  and switching loss function to BCEWithLogitsLoss(), and it looks like a downward trend. Do you think it's the correct way?

Comment: I guess `torch.round()` returns 1 if the value is >0 and -1 if the value is < 0. But my labels are {0,1}

Comment: `y_pred = torch.sigmoid(y_pred)` is working! Thank you. Could you explain a bit? I did the original line because I tried to convert predictions to {0, 1} before entering loss function. So that means I shouldn't do that?